# pushViewController Taking too much to show the view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a really light ViewController, it does nothing in viewDidLoad. I'm pushing this view on top of a navigationController. The method who does this action is called from inside a block.  After the call to showView I added an NSLog, and that log prints in the console really fast, but the view takes a lot to load... I really don't understand what maybe happening... any idea???

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
    [self showView];
    NSLog(@"EXECUTED");                
});

- (void) showView{
    TestViewController *test = [[TestViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:test animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: Can you post `TestViewController`? Hard to see what's happening here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs for `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion`:

> The completion handler is called on an arbitrary queue. If your app uses an address book throughout the app, you are responsible for ensuring that all usage of that address book is dispatched to a single queue to ensure correct thread-safe operation.

You should make sure your UI code is called on the main thread.

```
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBookRef, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error {
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [self showView];
         NSLog(@"EXECUTED");                
     });
});
```

Comment: Make sure to fix your syntax highlighting, I can't because they are only spaces

Comment: @NSAddict Thanks - I usually notice things like that.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the only problem, but according to the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABAddressBookRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion), the completion handler passed to `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` is called on an arbitrary queue. `-showView` should only be called on the main queue since it is dealing with `UIViewController` objects.

The other thing to ask is what else is happening on the main queue? Are there other long-running tasks that could be blocking UI updates?